# How to test pre-release iOS and Android OS

Tags: android, ios

This may be a simple question, but do Android and Apple make their new versions of OS available to developers prior to release so they can ensure compatibility with their apps after the release date? Or do they just release an OS and it's up to you to get the latest SDK after release and test with the new version.

Answer (score 0):

Yes at least for Android. They released L developer version prior to official release of Lollipop.

Answer (score 0):

You can always test your App in beta OS versions. However, beta OS versions often have breaking changes, which does not reflect the final result (i.e. experience may change from beta version to stable release version).

Take iOS beta version as example. You can download latest beta OS release from Apple Developer Portal. After you install the beta OS in your device (not simulator), you can test your App on it (remember to install the beta Xcode as well). Bear in mind that beta Xcode cannot be used to export Apps for App Store.